# QCamera Ready, QImageCapture Disagrees

Tags: qt, camera

I have the code as below. I have done multiple checks on the status, which is shown in the comments by qDebug(). I really cannot figure out where this is failing.

```
QCamera *camera = new QCamera();

camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);

camera->load();
camera->start();
camera->searchAndLock();

QCameraImageCapture *imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
imageCapture->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToFile);

imageCapture->capture("~/test.jpg");

qDebug() << camera->state();              // QCamera::ActiveStatus
qDebug() << camera->status();             // QCamera::LoadedStatus
qDebug() << camera->isAvailable();        // true
qDebug() << camera->errorString();        // ""
qDebug() << imageCapture->isAvailable();  // true
qDebug() << imageCapture->errorString();  // "Camera not ready"

camera->unlock();
camera->stop();
```

Comment: The destination path for your capture may be wrong. I'm not sure that it will be expand as you might expect. Try to debug with an existing regular path

Comment: Yes, I did try that. No avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QCamera *camera;

QList<QByteArray> devices = QCamera::availableDevices();
if( devices.length()){
    camera = new QCamera(devices.at(0));
}else{
    qDebug() << "No camera found!";
}
```

QCamera must be initialized with valid device.